# Multiple Conditions in laravel Relations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables, One is User table and another is Booking table (its basically a ticket booking application).

User Table:

```
userid    usertype
  01      normal
  02      agent
  03      normal
  ...      ...
```

And in Bookings Table:

```
bookingid    userid    createdAt    updatedAt
   01         01       01-09-2018   17-09-2018
   02         03       31-08-2018   12-09-2018
  ...        ...          ...          ...
```

What I need to do is filter total number of bookings done by user and agent on today (Particularly today). So I made a relation between user and booking table as follows:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'userid');
}
```

and user model :

```
public function bookings()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Booking', 'userid');
}
```

Now I need to fetch the total bookings for today by filtering `usertype` as normal and agent. For example - total number of booking done today (on booking table) by user or agent ( by checking user id from booking table I need to determine that its agent or normal user ) So that I can get a count of ticket booked by normal user and also agents.

The controller code I used is:

```
$booking = Booking::all();
$users = User::all();
$ticketUserToday = Booking::with('users')->get()->where(['usertype','=','agent'],['createdAt','>=',Carbon::Today()]);
```

But I am getting `null` value when dd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `->get()` followed by a `->where()` is not the same as querying the database; it will attempt to filter the `Collection` of `Bookings` you get from `Booking::get()`, which is why you're getting `null`; it can't filter properly due to a different signature of the `->where()` function between the `Builder` and `Collection` classes.

What you're looking for is a `->whereHas()` on your `Users` role, and a `->where()` on your `Booking` table:

```
$ticketsToday = Booking::with(["users"])
->where("createdAt", ">=", Carbon::today())
->whereHas("users" => function($subQuery){ 
   $subQuery->where("usertype", "=", "agent");
})->get();
```

What this will do is query your `Booking` table for the right date, then limit that result to any that has one or more `Users` with a `usertype` of "agent".

Comment: Wow, it works absolutely fine ! now how shall i get the count ? by adding count() at the end of the query ?

Comment: Couple different ways; if you replace `->get()` with `->count()`, then you can do `dd($ticketsToday)` and get a number. If you leave the `->get()`, then you can do `dd(count($ticketsToday))` to get a count (native php `count()` function)

Comment: If you leave the `get()`, you will get back a Laravel collection(), so you can use `->count()` on it instead of using the native PHP function for a more object-oriented approach.

Comment: Wait, read that wrong. Yes, you're correct; `Collections` have a `count()` method, so 3 approaches.

Comment: while using >= in carbon, i am getting value 1 for both agent and user ( but as it has only one record under user ) ! But when i use = i am getting 0 value for both ! what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: `Carbon::today()` generates `2018-09-17 00:00:00` (start of day), so `>=` would handle any `createdAt` timestamps for today and later. Setting to `=` would enforce hours, minutes and seconds each equaling `00:00:00`; what do your records look like in the DB? Is your `createdAt` a `timestamp` or `datetime` column? (Also, may be worthwhile to open another question; depends on how much new information you need to add)